# My app stops unfortunately when the player plays a song and after completion of the song i want to change bt the app get stopped

Tags: android, media-player

this is the code where after playing one song it should change top next bt the app get closed.Here on conpletion i want to change the song bt it get stopped

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpp) {
                                   mp.stop();
                                   mp.reset();
                                   mp.release();


                                   pos =(pos+1)% mysongs.size();
                                   String mediaPath =file.getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + mysongs.get(pos)+".wav";
                                   Log.d("pathh1", mediaPath);
                                   u = Uri.parse(mediaPath);
                                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                                   // mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                                   try {
                                       mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);
                                       mp.prepare();
                                       mp.start();
                                       th.start();
                                   } catch (IOException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }

                               }
                           });
```

ERROR:

---

```
05-31 17:24:52.908 9460-9460/php.example.abs.voicerecorder E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
05-31 17:25:02.798 9460-9460/php.example.abs.voicerecorder D/pathh1: /storage/sdcard/MediaRecorderSample/Recordingg4.wav
05-31 17:25:02.798 9460-9460/php.example.abs.voicerecorder D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-31 17:25:02.800 9460-9460/php.example.abs.voicerecorder D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM                                                                            --------- beginning of crash
05-31 17:25:02.801 9460-9460/php.example.abs.voicerecorder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: php.example.abs.voicerecorder, PID: 9460
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1119)
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1104)
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1083)
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1060)
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1014)
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:957)
                                                                                 at php.example.abs.voicerecorder.Player$2.onCompletion(Player.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2538)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: without seeing the error log, everything is just a guess, so please post this here..

Comment: and what is `th.start();` ? another mediaplayer object....

Comment: no that is a thread for seek..... i am posting the error log

Comment: that´s not the complete one. There must be more with the line of code which causes the error...

Answer (score 1):

One of the things going wrong in your code is, that you set the datasource after you created the player with the data source. That´s the wrong way:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                                   // mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                                   try {
                                       mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);
                                       mp.prepare();
```

As stated in the API:

***Calling setDataSource.... transfers a MediaPlayer object in the Idle state to the Initialized state. An IllegalStateException is thrown if setDataSource() is called in any other state.***

So you have already initialized your MediaPlayer object after releasing it by:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
```

and right after that you set the data source in the try/catch block:

```
mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);
```

That does not work because at this time, the MediaPlayer is not in the idle state anymore. The try/catch doesn´t catch the error because it throws an `IllegalStateException` and you just catch the `IOException`.

So the only thing you have to do is to delete

`mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);`

Comment: what does it mean "but I got it right" ? You code above shows definetely that you call `mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),u);` in the try/catch block and `mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);` before...